# IE8+, window.open(url/#/frag,'_parent') vs. parent.location.href=url/#/frag in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.open, fragment-identifier, window.parent

I have a site that loads an iframe. Code in the parent window registers an **onbeforeunload** listener.

Currently the iframe contains a button with a click handler that fires off:

`window.open(/#/frag,'_parent')`

In all browsers I have tested (besides **IE8/IE9**) this has the desired behavior of loading the parent fragment without triggering the **onbeforeunload** event.
however, if I change the iframe's click hander to fire off:

`parent.location.href='/#/frag'`

it works as desired in IE 8/9 as well.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

I included a simple example below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function registerUnloadListener(){
                window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                    return "onbeforeunload";
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="registerUnloadListener()">
        <iframe width="100%" src="iframe.html"></iframe><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setParentLocation(frag){
                parent.location.href = frag;
            }
            function openWindowInParent(frag){
                window.open(frag,'_parent');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        onbeforeunload triggered (as expected) -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setParentLocation('/')">
            parent.location.href = '/'
        </a><br/>

        onbeforeunload NOT triggered (as expected) -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setParentLocation('/#/frag')">
            parent.location.href = '/#/frag'
        </a><br/>

        onbeforeunload triggered for IE8/IE9 only (unexpected) -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openWindowInParent('/#/frag')">
            window.open("/#/frag",'_parent')
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Are you asking a form of the question "why does Internet Explorer do something wrong or something dumb?" Internet Explorer is a force of nature and explanations don't help much.

Comment: @Pointy I guess I'm looking to confirm that IE is doing it wrong and the other browsers are doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `return false;` to your anchors' `onclick` event. It is a known issue that anchors with `href="javascript:void(0);` trigger `onbeforeunload` in IE, but adding `return false;` to the click handler fixes that.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openWindowInParent('/#/frag'); return false;">
    window.open("/#/frag",'_parent')
</a>
```

Comment: @p e p Thanks, that is helpful information to have, but it isn't preventing the **onbeforeunload** in my case.

Comment: I wonder if the difference is due to having the link within a frame. Good luck, I'd like to hear if you are able to resolve this.